# ¿Cómo mostrar resultado de una Query en porcentaje?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente tengo esta query (que sí funciona):

```
        SELECT aerolinea,SUM(pasajeros) AS utilizado,SUM(capacidad) AS disponible,SUM(capacidad)-SUM(pasajeros) AS desperdiciado FROM vuelos GROUP BY aerolinea ORDER BY aerolinea ASC;
```

y me arroja este resultado:

| Aerolinea | utilizado | disponible | desperdiciado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aeroflot | 1738 | 4032 | 2294 |
| Aeromar | 6661 | 12389 | 5728 |

En la última columna, muestra la cantidad de asientos desperdiciados en total.

Pero me gustaría que la última columna, mostrara un resultado como "%56.89" haciendo referencia al porcentaje desperdiciado.

Intenté la siguiente query pero me marca error: *Error converting data type varchar to float.*

```
SELECT aerolinea,
    SUM(pasajeros) AS utilizado,
    SUM(capacidad) AS disponible,
    '%'+STR(100-((SUM(pasajeros)*100)/SUM(capacidad))) AS 
    desperdiciado
FROM vuelos GROUP BY aerolinea ORDER BY aerolinea ASC;
```

Puedo deducir que el error se encuentra en este fragmento:

`STR('%')+STR(100-((SUM(pasajeros)*100)/SUM(capacidad)))`

¿Cuál es la solución al error y la manera más efectiva de lograr lo que busco?

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de identar código en sql?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El calculo del porcentaje de no uso, se hace así:

```
((SUM(capacidad) - SUM(pasajeros))/SUM(capacidad)) * 100
```

Para agregar el símbolo de porcentaje:

```
'%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ((SUM(capacidad) - SUM(pasajeros))/SUM(capacidad)) * 100)
```

No puedo responder acerca del error, por que no has dicho cual es, pero posiblemente sea el uso de `STR` que no es una función de `sql-server`, en cuanto a la identación, no hay una guía ni un estándar, cada uno tiene su forma de identar que le resulta más fácil de leer.

Comment: Siempre que se utilice varchar, es importante asignar la longitud. Es una buena práctica que previene errores a futuro (aunque en este caso no afecte).